# Java Shortest Cost Path: Uninformed/Informed search from a (.txt) text file

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, helper, shortest-path

I am working on a Uninformed search assignment but I am stuck.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4n18.png

I have 90% of it working, however I am trying to:

1)  Load the data (cities and miles) from a .txt file instead of from the within the code. 
2)  Allow the program to take three command line input arguments: the input file name, origin city, and destination city

Example: findroute inputFilename originCity DestinationCity

Command line example: findroute input1.txt Munich Berlin

This is part of the  code I have right now:

```
    package graph;
   import java.util.Formatter;
   import java.util.List;
   import bisearch.UniformCostSearch;
   import search.Action;

public class findRoute {
   /**
    * finds the shortest path 
    */




      public static void main(final String[] args) {
           Graph graph = findRoute.Map();

           GraphStateSpaceSearchProblem sssp = new GraphStateSpaceSearchProblem(
              graph, " Zerind ", " Oradea ");

          bisearch.Search bisearch = new UniformCostSearch();
          List<Action> actions = bisearch.search(sssp);
  findRoute.printOutput(bisearch.nodesExplored(), actions);





   }


   /**
    * prints the path found
    */
   private static void printOutput(final int nodesExplored,
         final List<Action> actions) {


      double cost = 0;
      for (final Action action : actions)

     cost += action.cost();
      System.out.println("Distance: " + new Formatter().format("%.2f", cost)+" m");
      System.out.println ("Route: ");

      for (final Action action : actions)

         System.out.println(action);

   }



   /**
    * creates a map of as a Graph

    */


   private static Graph Map() {
      final Graph graph = new Graph();

      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Oradea", "Zerind", 71);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Zerind", "Arad", 75);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Arad", "Sibiu", 140);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Sibiu", "Oradea", 151);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Timisoara", "Arad", 118);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Timisoara", "Lugoj", 111);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Lugoj", "Mehadia", 70);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Mehadia", "Dobreta", 75);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Dobreta", "Craiova", 120);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Sibiu", "Fagaras", 99);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Fagaras", "Bucharest", 211);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Sibiu", "Rimnicu Vilcea", 80);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Pitesti", "Rimnicu Vilcea", 97);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Craiova", "Rimnicu Vilcea", 146);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Craiova", "Pitesti", 136);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Pitesti", "Bucharest", 101);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Bucharest", "Giurgiu", 90);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Bucharest", "Urziceni", 85);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Urziceni", "Hirsova", 98);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Hirsova", "Eforie", 86);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Urziceni", "Vaslui", 142);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Vaslui", "Iasi", 92);
      graph.addUndirectedEdge("Neamt", "Iasi", 87);
      return graph;


}

}
```

I just can’t figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) Read the file line by line, split the lines by your seperator and you should be good to go (google how to do that)

2) The program already accepts parameters. They are in your args array. You just have to use them (args[0], args[1]...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use args[]. Command line parameters are passed as an array to java program through args[] variable.

```
args[0] = inputFilename
args[1] = originCity 
args[2] = DestinationCity
```

Fill the map by parsing the file. Rest of the code should work as it is.

Comment: typically on homework the recommended way is to explain the concept instead of providing code, unless absolutely critical to the explanation.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - It's not the code he needs, it's just an illustration of the args array...I'm all for not posting complete solutions on homework tags, but this is far from it.

Answer (score 0):

For part 1 you want to use the File object that Java provides OOB for you.  You will then need to read in the values from that file I would recommend the FileReader object.  When you instantiate the File object you will need to use the index lookup from the `args` String array.

For the second part, the program already does that.  If you want to limit the number of arguments you need to check the args.length variable against what your desired input parameters will be.